# (BASH)How to remove default 'newline' operator in command

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, newline, output

I have a command:

```
find /etc -type f \( ! -perm /o=w \) -exec /usr/bin/ls -hastl '{}' \; -exec /usr/bin/md5sum '{}' \; > somefile.log
```

and this command creates such printout (i need to have no breaking line) :

```
...
4.0K -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 332 Oct 23  2012 /etc/xinetd.d/rsync
fd32314f3157aaf15712e6da7758060d  /etc/xinetd.d/rsync
....
```

question: what I must add to this command to remove new line operation to get such result:

```
(...) is '-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 332 Oct 23  2012'

...
4.0K (...) /etc/xinetd.d/rsync >> fd32314f3157aaf15712e6da7758060d  /etc/xinetd.d/rsync
...
```

Comment: the question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO You can only execute one command with exec. A possible solution might be you execute "sh -c" so you can use pipes and similar:

With one newline at the end:

```
find /etc -type f -exec sh -c "/bin/ls -hastl '{}' | tr '\n' ' '" \; -exec /usr/bin/md5sum '{}' \;
```

without any newline:

```
find /etc -type f -exec sh -c "/bin/ls -hastl '{}' | tr '\n' ' '" \; -exec sh -c "/usr/bin/md5sum '{}'| tr -d '\n' " \;
```

Comment: But i`m getting line : 4.0K -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 451 May 17 15:17 /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/01-cgi.conf 36e54d4b2bd190f5cbad876bfbeda461  /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/01-cgi.conf - how to remove duplicating of filepath?

Comment: `find /etc -type f -exec sh -c "/bin/ls -hastl '{}' | tr '\n' ' '" \; -exec sh -c "/usr/bin/md5sum '{}' | cut -d ' ' -f 1 " \;`

Answer (score 1):

How about a command such as

```
echo "$(ls -hastl '{}') >> $(md5sum '{}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two join every pair of adjacent lines just pipe your output to `awk 'NR%2{line=$0;next}{print line sep $0}' sep=" >> "` adjusting `sep` to your need.

**Addendum:**

In response to the original author's comment I am going to explain some details of this solution:

`awk` processes input record-wise, without further options that is line-by-line.
The (internal) variable `NR` stores the current record's number. `%` is the modulus operator, so `NR%2` evaluates to `1` for odd line numbers and `0` for even line numbers. `{...}` groups commands (so called 'action') to perform. Since `1` is considered "true" and `0` "false" the first action is only performed for odd line numbers. This action consists of two commands: First, the whole line (`$0`) is stored in the variable `line` and then the `next` record is processed (without considering any other action). For even lines, this action is not performed, so the second action is considered. Since there is no expression before the `{` the action is performed: the stored (i.e. previous) `line` is concatenated with a variable called `sep` and the current line (`$0`). The resulting string is printed (and automatically appended by *one* new-line in the end). The value of `sep` is handed to `awk` as a parameter to make it easy to adjust it without messing with the script. Since `awk` reads standard input and output without further arguments you can just pipe (`|`) the output of your find to `awk` (`find ... -exec ... -exec ... | awk ... > ...`)

Comment: Nice point of look, but I dont know how to use awk , but i`ll try to learn

Comment: @user2424174 I added some explanation to help you understand my answer and encourage you to learn awk. ;-)